# CSS nth-of-type not logical

Tags: css, css-selectors

CSS:

```
.banner:nth-of-type(1) {background-color:red;}
.banner:nth-of-type(2) {background-color:blue;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="copy">copy 1</div>
  <div class="banner">banner 1</div>
  <div class="copy">copy 1</div>
  <div class="banner">banner 2</div>
  <div class="copy">copy 1</div>
  <div class="banner">banner 3</div>
  <div class="banner">banner 4</div>
</div>
```

Shouldn't the CSS be counting the `.banner` elements regardless of the other sibling elements?

I'm expecting banner 1 to have a red background and banner 2 to have a blue background, but getting banner 1 with a blue background and banner 2 with no background -- I would expect this if I were using `nth-child(n)`.  Check my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JjNBV/3/

Comment: You can't use nth-of-type on a class.

Comment: `nth-of-type` applies to the type of element -- ie `<div>` in this case, not to the class.

Answer (score 5):

`nth-of-type` applies to the type of element -- ie `<div>` in this case, not to the class.

- `.banner:nth-of-type(1)` doesn't match anything because none of the `.banner` elements is the first `div` inside the `container`.
- `.banner:nth-of-type(2)` matches the first `.banner` element because it is the second `div` inside the `container`.

There isn't a CSS3 selector that matches classes in the way you're expecting.

If you want this kind of behaviour, you will need to use different element types for your banners and copy, then `nth-of-type` will work for you as you want. HTML5 provides several elements that may meet your needs in this regard.

Which elements you use would depend on what you're using them for; your supplied code doesn't give sufficient clues for me to give you a definitive recommendation, but here's your code with the `copy` elements changed from `<div>` into `<article>` elements...

```
<div id="container">
  <article class="copy">copy 1</article>
  <div class="banner">banner 1</div>
  <article class="copy">copy 1</article>
  <div class="banner">banner 2</div>
  <article class="copy">copy 1</article>
  <div class="banner">banner 3</div>
  <div class="banner">banner 4</div>
</div>
```

With this change, your existing CSS should now work as you expect. (and [here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MPVp3/) to show it working)

CSS4 does have a selector [`nth-match()`](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/structural-pseudo-class/) which may possibly also do what you're looking for, but no browsers support this selector (nor are any looking likely to in the near future), so that's not really an option for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 .copy:nth-child(n+1) {background-color:red;}
 .banner:nth-child(n+2) {background-color:blue;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JjNBV/4/) here